# Why is the PHP ipc message not in the queue?

Tags: php, ipc

In PHP I try to send a message through IPC, and to immediately check if the message is in the queue. Here is a test code:

```
$rQueue = msg_get_queue(12345, 0660);
msg_send($rQueue, 0, "test", FALSE, FALSE);
print_r(msg_stat_queue($rQueue));
```

which prints out the statistics from the given queue, indicating `msg_qnum=0`, i.e. no messages are in the queue. The expected behavior is to see at least one message in the queue instead. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.msg-send.php) it says:

```
bool msg_send ( resource $queue , int $msgtype , mixed $message [, bool $serialize = true [, bool $blocking = true [, int &$errorcode ]]] )
```

> msg_send() sends a message of type msgtype (which MUST be greater than
>   0) to the message queue specified by queue.

So changing the second parameter from 0 to 1 solves the problem.

Please also have a look at the [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function. When I run your code, PHP indicated the problem with a Warning:

> PHP Warning:  msg_send(): msgsnd failed: Invalid argument